# Get only the first element of a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, indexof, map-function

I have the following code, which the purpose it is to be reused inside another component, and give a different link according to the id of my object, and my API return.

The problem is that, how I'm using a map function it is reproducing the same button multiple times on the screen. I want to know how I get only one button. Can I somehow use indexOf inside that map?
Everything else is working just fine

```
    const ButtonGroup = (linksReturn) => {
      return linksReturn.map((urlAdress, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <button
              target="_blank"
              href={urlAdress["detailsUrl"]}
            >
              Acess Link
            </button>
          </div>
      ));
    };
    const PreviewActions = ({ linksReturn }) => {
      return <div>{ButtonGroup(linksReturn)}</div>;
    };
    export default PreviewActions;
```

This is the part of the code where I reuse the button

```
    import { useEffect } from 'react';
    import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
    import PreviewActions from './PreviewActions';

    // ** Store & Actions
    import { getInfo } from '../store/actions/index';
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';


    const LicitacaoPreview = () => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const store = useSelector((state) => state.allInfo);

      const { id } = useParams();
      
      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getInfo(id));
      }, [dispatch]);

      return typeof store.lotesData === 'object' ? (
        <div>
              <PreviewActions
                id={id}
                linksReturn={store.infoData}
              />
        </div>
      ) 
    };

    export default LicitacaoPreview;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map()` does not work like that, it calls the function passed in as an argument on every single array elements and returns the resultant array.

A better approach would be using `Array.prototype.slice()` to return specific part of the original array and then use `map()` on it

```js
const ButtonGroup = (linksReturn) => {
    const newArr = linksReturn.slice(startindex, endindex); // replace with your index appropriately
    return newArr.map((urlAdress, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <button
                target="_blank"
                href={urlAdress["detailsUrl"]}
            >
                Acess Link
            </button>
        </div>
    ));
};
```

Comment: no problem happy to help